# bash script to rename all files recursively based on name from stat

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am trying to run a bash script using the `find` command on a terminal in osx and getting an error `rename_file: command not found`.  I am including the script I wrote below.  Is there an issue with the way I am calling the function when I execute `find`?

My goal is to then organize these files into specific directories by month, but I haven't gotten that far as the error is holding me up.

Thanks for any tips as to what I am doing wrong!

```
#!/bin/bash

base_dir="."  

# Function to rename files based on their creation date
rename_file() {
    local file="$1"
    local file_prefix
    local year
    local month
    local day

    # Get the creation date of the file
    creation_date=$(stat -f "%SB" -t "%Y%m%d" "$file")

    # Extract year, month, and day from the creation date
    year=${creation_date:0:4}
    month=${creation_date:4:2}
    day=${creation_date:6:2}

    # Construct the new filename
    file_prefix="${year}_${month}_${day}_"
    new_filename="${file_prefix}$(basename "$file")"

    # Rename the file
    echo "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$new_filename"
    #mv "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$new_filename"
}

# Find and process files in the base directory and its subdirectories
find "$base_dir" -type f -exec bash -c 'rename_file "$0"' {} \;

echo "File renaming completed."
```

Comment: Maybe `-exec` spawns another shell?

Comment: @jml It is missing `export -f rename_file` just before running `find` because inside find it spawns another bash instance which does not know about your defined function; unless it has been exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your last 3 lines with these, it will work

```
export -f rename_file
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'rename_file "$@"'  {} +
echo "File renaming completed."
```